# How to write to Parcel a List of Serializable (not Parcelable)

Tags: android, parcelable, serializable, parcel

I'm using mapsforge library which has LatLong object for storing points on map. Unfortunatelly it only implement Serializable interface, not Parcelable.

```
public class LatLong implements Comparable<LatLong>, Serializable
```

In my app I have object (lets call it Result) which stores among others list of LatLong points:

```
List<LatLong> points;
```

My class Result implements Parcelable.

My question is how to write to Parcel a List, where LatLong is Serializable but not Parcelable?
writeSerializable, writeTypedList not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `writeToParcel()` method, use this code:

```
dest.writeInt(latLongList.size());
for (LatLong latLong : latLongList) {
  dest.writeDouble(latLong.latitude);
  dest.writeDouble(latLong.longitude);
}
```

In your private object constructor called from `CREATOR.createFromParcel(Parcel source)`, use this code:

```
latLongList = new ArrayList<LatLong>();
int size = source.readInt();
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
  double lat = source.readDouble();
  double lon = source.readDouble();
  latLongList.add(new LatLong(lat, lon));
}
```

I'm basing this on the JavaDocs I found at [mapsforge.org](https://github.com/mapsforge/mapsforge)

Comment: Thanks, it's working. Another solution is to use parcel.writeValue